# Will including an Android layout choose between hdpi/mdpi/ldpi layouts as for full layouts?

Tags: android, layout, resources, include, dpi

Suppose I have a layout in the main, non-DPI specific layout resource folder, and that layout does an `<include>` of a sub layout that exists in both the hdpi/mdpi/ldpi folders. Can I expect the final inflated layout to aggregate either the h/m/l-dpi sub layout depending on the device DPI, just as for "full" layouts?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this on the emulator yet? :D

Comment: Why do you have different *layouts* for screen density?

Comment: do you really mean *layouts*?

Comment: @LokeshMehra Yeah, I mean layouts. I have a section of the UI that needs special layout for low-DPI, whereas the rest is OK. My speculation was whether the include mechanism would be a viable approach for picking the right DPI-specifc "fragment" to include. I have since confirmed that this seems to work and will answer my own post with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas at the time of the post I did not have an opportunity to test out the proposition of the post, I have since had a chance to do so, and thus will answer my own question, since noone else has done so.

Yes, the following scenario works as expected (tested at API level 8):

layout/main.xml:

```
... <include layout="@layout/included"/> ...
```

layout/included.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GENERIC included fragment"/>
</merge>
```

layout-ldpi/included.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOW-DPI included fragment"/>
</merge>
```

Running the app on, say, a QVGA device renders a view in which the included part is from the LDPI directory as desired, whereas a non LDPI device grabs the default one from the layout directory.